# An interesting combo question about the lights on-off game

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, combinatorial-game-theory

There are n lights, one at each vertex of a regular $n$-gon. Only one light is on at first, each time you can select some vertices to form a regular $m$-gon($m|n$) and change the state of all lights on these vertices, which is called an **operation**.

What kind of $n$ makes it possible to turn all lights on after a finite number of operations?

---

I am trying to abstract the states of all lights into a polynomial whose coefficients are in $\{0,1\}$ and at first $f(x)=1$. Through the unit-root trick as follows,

$$\dfrac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(e^{\frac{2k\pi i}m})^n=[m|n]$$

we can extract the terms $a_0,a_mx^m,a_{2m}x^{2m},...,a_{m[n/m]}x^{m[n/m]}$ of a polynomial. In fact,

$$\dfrac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}f(xe^{\frac{2k\pi i}m})=\sum_{j=0}^na_jx^j\dfrac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(e^{\frac{2k\pi i}m})^j=\sum_{j=0}^na_jx_j[m|j]=a_0+a_mx^m+...+a_{m[n/m]}x^{m[n/m]}$$

But I don't know how to flip their coefficients accordingly(from $0$ to $1$ or from $1$ to $0$).

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Not sure if I have misunderstood since this seems an obvious counterexample: if $n=3$ you can only turn on and off three lights simultaneously and it seems clear you will never be able to turn them all on.

Comment: A similar idea can be said for any $p$-gon, for $p$ a prime number. But then I imagine the natural next question is "okay, it doesn't work in some cases: but for which cases does it work?"

Comment: @SuzuHirose It does. The proposition holds for some $n$ and not for others. What kind of $n$ fits this proposition?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You are right. In fact, that's exactly what I wonder.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's no solution for $n=6$ even if you allow $2$-gons.

Comment: You can only turn on two or three at a time, but it isn't possible to get to a stage where you have two opposites which are both off by flipping on triangles.

Comment: $n=9$ is trivially impossible in almost the same way as $n=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such $n$ does not exist.

Let the state be $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_2[x] / (x^n-1)$, suppose we have a regular $m$-gon, then its state can be written as $\frac{x^n-1}{x^{n/m}-1} \cdot x^i$, our question is that, can $1$ be a linear combination of the state of the $m$-gon? That is, we have the equation under the field $\mathbb{F}_2$,
$$ 1 = \left(\sum_{m\geq 3, m\mid n} \frac{x^n-1}{x^{n/m}-1} g_m(x)\right) \bmod (x^n-1),$$
for some $g_m(x)$. Then, we can rewrite the equation as
$$ 1 = \left(\sum_{m\geq 3, m\mid n} \frac{x^n-1}{x^{n/m}-1} g_m(x)\right) + d(x) (x^n-1), $$
for some $d(x)$. Recall that $\mathbb F_2[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, such solution exists if and only if the greatest common divisor of the polynomials
$$ \left\{ \frac{x^n-1}{x^{n/m-1}} : m \geq 3, m\mid n \right\} \cup \{ x^n - 1 \} $$
is $1$. But since in $\mathbb Q[x]$, $x^n-1$ has the decomposition
$$ x^n - 1 = \prod_{d\mid n} \Phi_d(x), $$
where $\Phi_d(x)$ is [the cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), we must have
$$ \frac{x^n-1}{x^{n/m}-1} = \prod_{d\mid n, d\nmid \frac n m} \Phi_d(x), $$
then we have $\Phi_n(x) \mid \frac{x^n-1}{x^{n/m}-1}$. Since this holds in $\mathbb Q[x]$ and they are all monic polynomials with integer coefficients, we must have $\Phi_n(x) \mid \frac{x^n-1}{x^{n/m}-1}$ in $\mathbb F_2[x]$.

Then the linear combination must be a multiple of $\Phi_n(x)$, since $\deg \Phi_n(x) = \phi(n) \geq 1$, it cannot be $1$.

Comment: Thank you & orz